# Java TLS-PSK socket

Tags: java, android, ssl

I am new to java and am trying to add some security to my socket and I would prefer PSK methods. I have found a java library that implements TLS-PSK, [JESSIE-PSK-TLS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jessie-psk-tls/), but I cannot figure out how to actually utilize this library. I have looked at the [JSSE reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SecureConnSample) manual for reference; but I am still clueless. I would greatly appreciate a simple example using TLS-PSK.

Eventually this will be incorporated into an android application.

I have a test server set up for accepting tls-psk clients through tlslite for python and have verified that a python client can connect, complete the handshake and transfer data.

Comment: PSK requires support on both sides and I have yet to see complete server-side support for PSK (with interfaces to specify the key etc).

Comment: I have a testing server using [TLS Lite](http://trevp.net/tlslite/) for python.

Comment: There is an open source solution for this now available at: https://github.com/clover/pskfactories

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [bouncy castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) its the de facto package for reading and using certificates in Java.  BTW, if your going to install that on Android, you should also take a look at Spongy Castle.
I also found the following related topic [TLS connection with PSK using Bouncycastle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154263/tls-connection-with-psk-using-bouncycastle)