# TLS connection with PSK using Bouncycastle

Tags: java, sockets, cryptography, bouncycastle, ssl

I have to establish a TLS connection to a remote server with a preshared key. I'm currently using PSKTlsClient from Bouncycastle. My initialization code looks like that:

```
 socket_ = new Socket(address,port);            
 tlsHandler_ = new TlsProtocolHandler(socket_.getInputStream(),socket_.getOutputStream());           
 pskTlsClient_ = new PSKTlsClient(tlsPskInfo_);            
 tlsHandler_.connect(pskTlsClient_);
```

However Im getting this stacktrace:

```
java.io.IOException: Internal TLS error, this could be an attack
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsProtocolHandler.failWithError(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsProtocolHandler.safeReadData(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsProtocolHandler.connect(Unknown Source)
at common.network.Transport.PskTlsClientSocket.connect(PskTlsClientSocket.java:61)
```

I also got a TLS Certificate in the message, where the PSK is transmitted, but I'm somehow stuck how to establish this connection. Do you have any suggestion how to proceed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved. The problem was, that in the java bouncycastle library, the process server certificate method wasn't implemented and always throws an internal error. So i had to implement this and all worked fine after that.

Edit:
In TlsPSKKeyExchange.java change the following method to:

```
public void processServerCertificate(Certificate serverCertificate) throws IOException
{
    SubjectPublicKeyInfo subPubKeyInfo = serverCertificate.certs[0].getTBSCertificate().getSubjectPublicKeyInfo();
    RSAPublicKey pubKey = RSAPublicKey.getInstance(subPubKeyInfo.getPublicKey());
    rsaServerPublicKey = new RSAKeyParameters(false,pubKey.getModulus(),pubKey.getPublicExponent());
}
```

The first public key in the first certificate is used for the RSA encryption.

Comment: Could you please post an example snippet for others?

Comment: I'm not sure of the relevant timing, but the latest version of BC (1.49) has TlsPSKKeyExchange.processServerCertificate implemented, so it should no longer be necessary to make this change.